# How to draw binary tree in vanilla JS to HTML+CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm stuck when doing my homework. I need to convert my js binary-tree to Html+css, without using any hmtl code. Only vanilla js.

I got tree and recursive function that adding all tree elment to page, but i need it to be like ul, li.

```
const Node = {
    data: 10,
    left: {
        data: 1,
        left: null,
        right: null
    },
    right: {
        data: 7,
        left: {
            data: 6,
            left: {
                data: 4,
                left: null,
                right: null
            }, 
            right: null
        },
        rigth: null
    }
};

const breadthFirst = function (node) {
    function bf(queue) {
        let newQueue = [];
        queue.forEach(function (node) {
            console.log(node.data);
            const newEl = document.createElement('div');
            newEl.innerText = node.data;
            document.getElementById("app").appendChild(newEl)
            node.left && newQueue.push(node.left);
            node.right && newQueue.push(node.right);
        });
        newQueue.length && bf(newQueue);
    }

    bf([node]);
};

breadthFirst(Node);
```

So i've got all elments in column, but need to be like ordered list:

- firstel

  - second

    - fourth
    - fifth
  - third

and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to build up the multi-level structure of your tree you will need to append the sub elements to their parents. I seperated this to 2 functions.

```js
const data = {
    data: 10,
    left: {
        data: 1,
        left: null,
        right: null
    },
    right: {
        data: 7,
        left: {
            data: 6,
            left: {
                data: 4,
                left: null,
                right: null
            }, 
            right: null
        },
        rigth: null
    }
};

const createListItem = (treeNode) => {
    if (!treeNode) {
        return;
    }
    
    let item, subTree;
    
    item = document.createElement('li');
    item.textContent = treeNode.data;
    
    subTree = createSubTreeForNode(treeNode);
    if (subTree) {
        item.appendChild(subTree);
    }
    
    return item;
};

const createSubTreeForNode = (treeNode) => {
    if (!treeNode.left && !treeNode.right) {
        return;
    }
    
    let list, item;
    
    list = document.createElement('ul');
    
    item = createListItem(treeNode.left);
    if (item) {
        list.appendChild(item);
    }
    
    item = createListItem(treeNode.right);
    if (item) {
        list.appendChild(item);
    }
   
    return list;
};

const renderTree = (treeNode, parentElement) => {
    parentElement = parentElement || document.getElementById("app");
    
    let rootList, item;
    
    rootList = document.createElement('ul');
    item     = createListItem(treeNode);
    if (item) {
        rootList.appendChild(item);
    }
    
    parentElement.appendChild(rootList);
};

renderTree(data);
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks u so much!